# How to check PDF/A conformance of existing document with iText 7?

Tags: java, pdf, itext7, pdfa

I'm trying to check the conformance (PDF/A-1B) of an existing PDF document with iText. Unfortunately it only checks the conformance for newly created elements in document but ignores existing parts of document.

```
byte[] pdf = ...; // pdf document which claims to be conform but is not conform (1 font is not embedded)
final PdfADocument pdfADocument = new PdfADocument(new PdfReader(new ByteArrayInputStream(pdf)), 
     new PdfWriter(new ByteArrayOutputStream()));

pdfADocument.close();
```

If I add something not conform to `pdfADocument` then the call to `close()` throws a `PdfAConformanceException`.

I only find example about creating documents with PDF/A conformance but no example about just validating an existing document.

Is there a way to check conformance with iText 7 for an existing document?

Comment: AFAIK iText just tries to make sure it itself does not introduce any issues but it does not contain a PDF/A  validator.

Comment: I confirm: iText isn't a PDF validator. The EU is sponsoring the development of an open source PDF/A validator (and I believe we have someone in the advisory board of that development), so why would we invest in writing one? See http://verapdf.org/ for more info.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie Thank you for your response. I think you could add your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Originally posted as a comment (because it felt too short to be a real answer), but now added as an answer as requested by the OP:

@mkl wrote: *AFAIK iText just tries to make sure it itself does not introduce any issues but it does not contain a PDF/A validator.*

I answered: *I confirm. iText isn't a PDF validator.*

The EU is sponsoring the development of an open source PDF/A validator
and iText is following up on its development through the [PDF Association](https://www.pdfa.org/).
There are no plans at iText to develop another validator to compete with
the one funded by the EU.

See [verapdf.org](http://verapdf.org/) for more info.